# two RGBD sensors in the same USB controller

Tags: usb, xtion, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all;
I m experiencing problems when connecting two RGB-D sensors to the same PC, using the same USB controller (two Asus Xtion, 1 Xtion and one Orbbec astra, etc).
Both are attached to the same USB controller (see arrows):

```
 tekniker@tekniker-mountain-2:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2bc5:0401  <--
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:066d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS  <--
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
tekniker@tekniker-mountain-2:~$
```

When I launch one (openni2_launch, astra_launch) the other that is already running automatically dies (I launch both of them specifying their camera ID):

```
[ INFO] [1509630757.804814665]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1509630758.688512003]: Device "1d27/0601@1/10" found.
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
[ WARN] [1509630761.855440698]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1509630761.855485428]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
[FATAL] [1509630762.038086038]: Failed to unload nodelet '/camera/driver` from manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
[camera/rgb_rectify_color-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/tekniker/.ros/log/15d2617e-bfd5-11e7-bf2b-94659ca95c36/camera-rgb_rectify_color-4*.log
```

And

```
rocess[camera_base_link3-14]: started with pid [30248]
[ INFO] [1509630761.818433804]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[FATAL] [1509630762.029871150]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/driver` of type `astra_camera/AstraDriverNodelet` to manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
[camera/driver-2] process has died [pid 30158, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load astra_camera/AstraDriverNodelet camera_nodelet_manager ir:=ir rgb:=rgb depth:=depth depth_registered:=depth_registered rgb/image:=rgb/image_raw depth/image:=depth_registered/image_raw __name:=driver __log:=/home/tekniker/.ros/log/15d2617e-bfd5-11e7-bf2b-94659ca95c36/camera-driver-2.log].
log file: /home/tekniker/.ros/log/15d2617e-bfd5-11e7-bf2b-94659ca95c36/camera-driver-2*.log
```

Does anyone have a clue of what is happening?. It seems both of them are trying to access to the same nodelet... is there a way to solve this?

Thank you in advance,
Best,
Alberto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274866/two-rgbd-sensors-in-the-same-usb-controller/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2017-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for the shutdown:

> Reason given for shutdown: [new node
> registered with same name]

You could create a new launch file that includes the two launch files, but puts them in different namespaces (check ns-argument in the [include](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include) statement.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0